# Missing "Bluetooth settings"

Tags: settings, system, bluetooth

Recently I noticed that I don't have "Bluetooth" tab in my System settings. When I press the Bluetooth icon in my taskbar and press "Bluetooth settings..." it just opens up "System settings" window and that's it.

Is anyone having the same problem? Previously I had the tab and could easily add/remove devices but now it's just gone.

Thank you for your help already and have a nice day!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known bug.

You can try installing 
'sudo apt install switchboard-plug-bluetooth'

It should add bluetooth setting to your system settings menu up to next system update.

Moreover, I turn on my Bluetooth with
'bluetooth on'
Command.
Then I'm able to connect to devices from tray icon.

However, Bluetooth right now is in a ruin and I hope so that it'll be repaired soon.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I too use `bluetooth on/off` when needed but disconnecting a device is easier from the GUI. When you say it's a known bug, where you found info about it? For next time I run into some issues.

Comment: I know it from this website :) I've been looking for help too and  read a bunch of posts of other people with similar problems. Although, on bugs.launchpad.net there are some officially described bugs.

Answer (score -1):

If that doesn't work, this commands gets it in the wing-panel as well as the switchboard
sudo apt-get install indicator-bluetooth